# setGeometryFlipped in awakeFromNib don't work

Tags: objective-c, macos

I wrote below in **awakeFromNib**:

```
layer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
[layer setGeometryFlipped:YES];
...
```

this code don't work on MacOS 10.8 but work in 10.7
and I tried *setGeometryFlipped* in **initWithFrame**, and got same result.

Anyone know the reason?

Comment: By "don't work" just what do you mean? A compiler error?  Compiles, but doesn't do the expected at run time?

Comment: I am sorry for my incomplete description. there is no error, the result is just like I didn't write *"[layer setGeometryFlipped:YES];"*. the contents of layer is displayed from left bottom corner.

Answer (score 0):

I found some Tips in "**Application Kit Release Notes for OS X v10.8**":

> • On 10.8, AppKit will control the  Prior to 10.8, a flipped view
>   would explicitly control a layer's position by updating it every call
>   to setFrameSize:. However, this conflicts with allowing CoreAnimation
>   to do frame size animations on a background thread without input from
>   AppKit. To solve this, AppKit now controls the -geometryFlipped on the
>   backing CALayer. Prior to 10.8, the anchorPoint was also set to be
>   either (0,0) or (0,1) -- it varied depending on the superview being
>   isFlipped or not. On 10.8, the layer's frame is now equal to the
>   view's frame. The anchorPoint is also always set to be (0,0), since
>   the positions are now equal. In order to properly control the flipped
>   state of a layer, override -isFlipped on NSView.
>   。。。。。。 
>   following properties on a CALayer (both when "layer-hosted" or "layer-backed"):
>   geometryFlipped, bounds, frame (implied), position, anchorPoint,
>   transform, shadow*, hidden, filters, and compositingFilter.
>   geometryFlipped is only changed for apps that link on 10.8 and higher.
>   Use the appropriate NSView cover methods to change these properties.

so, I used overriding isFlipped method instead of geometryFlipped.
it worked normally.